# How to access google group information

Tags: ruby, google-oauth

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, 'CLIENT_ID', 'CLIENT_SECRET',
    scope: 'email, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly'
end

class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    auth = request.env['omniauth.auth']
    groups = auth.extra.raw_info.groups
    # Process the groups data as needed
    # ...
  end
end
```

My config looks above.
when I inspect groups, its coming as nil. can you please advise.

Comment: Are you logged in with a user who has access?

Comment: Can you tell me if it needs a special access, I tried it on the workspace account also where groups are setup, still its coming as nil